# C Illegal instruction: 4 upon assignment to a global variable

Tags: c

I am working on a compiler project using lex and yacc, and have declared a global "localVarCount" initialized to zero. when this function is called by the generated yacc code, and localVarCount is assigned to in any way, it throws the "Illegal instruction: 4" error during runtime. The offending line is shown below. I do similar incrementing and assignment to that variable in other functions with no problems.

```
void insertArrayScopedName(char * name, int arraySize) {
  int VarCount = localVarCount;
  enterName(localTable, name);
  if(arraySize < 1) {
    writeIndicator(getCurrentColumnNum());
    writeMessage("Cannot declare an array with a size smaller than 1");
    errorFlag1++;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
    setCurrentAttr(localTable, (void *) VarCount);
    VarCount++;
  }
  localVarCount = VarCount; //Offending line
  return;
}
```

Comment: `setCurrentAttr(localTable, (void *) VarCount);` looks werid. Why you are using something not a pointer as a pointer? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It is an odd usage, I admit.```localTable``` is a table with entries (structs) that hold a char * and a void pointer to hold different types of structs (or attributes of that entry ). ```setCurrentAttr``` simply sets an attribute of an entry.  In this case, rather that malloc-ing some sort of space for a single int, I just store the int value I want to keep as the pointer. 

I will soon post a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: `(void *) VarCount` --> `(void *) &VarCount`

Comment: I ran this on another linux machine and it ran fine. I'm guessing that it has something to do with the memory on my mac, somehow. I've also read this error is common to certain Mac OS versions. I'm running Catalina 10.15.4. But I've worked around this for now.